# OpenGL Vertex Array not showing up?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm trying to render the simplest triangle with shaders and vertex arrays, but when I try to draw the vertex array, nothing shows up. This is the code (By the way, the draw function *is* being called, i checked):

## Array creation:

```
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);

glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

GLfloat verts[] = { 
    0, 0, /*vertex 1*/     1, 0, 0, /*color 1*/
    0, 100, /*vertex 2*/   0, 1, 0, /*color 2*/
    100, 0, /*vertex 3*/   0, 0, 1  /*color 3*/
};
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 5 * sizeof(GLfloat) * 3, verts, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, sizeof(GLfloat) * 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, sizeof(GLfloat) * 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

glBindVertexArray(0);
```

## Array Render:

```
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

## shader.vert

```
uniform float u_time;
uniform mat4 u_projMatrix;

in vec2 position;
in vec3 color;

out vec4 vertColor;
void main()
{
    gl_Position = u_projMatrix * vec4(position, 0.0, 1.0);
    vertColor = vec4(color, 1.0);
}
```

## shader.frag

```
uniform float u_time;

in vec4 vertColor;
void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = vertColor;
}
```

## Projection Matrix:

```
glm::mat4 projection = glm::scale(glm::vec3(2.0/800.0, 2.0/600.0, 1.0));
```

I haven't shown the entire code in my program, but is there anything that is definitely wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't specify a stride or offset. and the size is the number of components not the number of byte.

stride is how many byte openGL should advance for the next set of data for the attribute in your case that is `5*sizeof(GLfloat)` for both attributes.

offset is where the first set of data for the attribute is located, for position that is `0` for the color that is `2*sizeof(GLFoat)`.

so your `glVertexAttribPointer` calls should be:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, false, 5*sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 5*sizeof(GLfloat), 2*sizeof(GLfloat));
```

Comment: I had to cast `2*sizeof(GLfloat)` to `void*` but even then it didn't render anything. Anything I'm still doing wrong?

Comment: The second argument to `glVertexAttribPointer()` is the number of components, not the size in bytes.

Comment: if you don't specify the stride then openGL will see the following vertices: `0,0` `1,0` and `0,0` which is not what you want

Comment: @RetoKoradi I looked over that

Comment: @RetoKoradi Ohhhh. Thanks. It seems to draw just fine now! I thought it meant the size in bytes.

Comment: By the way, since I plan to be able to change the vertex buffer at any time (with `glBufferData`), should I use `GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW` or `GL_STATIC_DRAW`?

Comment: @name doesn't really matter since openGL guarantees either will work but dynamic is the better choice

Comment: If you change the vertex buffer with `glBufferData()`, I don't think the usage hint will matter. That's more intended for the case where you update the data with `glBufferSubData()`.